# How to POST multi-part/form-data with VEGETA

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, vegeta

I am using Vegeta to make POST requests with multi-part/form-data, but running into issues with the actual file not being sent

upload.txt

```
POST {url}
Authorization: {token}
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary={boundary}
@./queries/test/upload-form.txt
```

file.txt

```
------boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="0"; filename="image.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

[File Content Goes Here]
------boundary--
```

My request makes it to my service, but the actual image does not get sent because I do not know what the "File Content" looks like.

I've used POSTMAN to make the request, which is successful, but that is because POSTMAN allows you to actually attach a file to the request. Any idea what data format the [File Content] should be?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

It was discovered that I could use fs.createReadStream() to append the file content to my .txt file :)

Comment: Would you please share more detail or your code snippet ? thank you